# Calculate required transmit power of Wi-Fi-router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Is there a way to calculate required transmit power of Wi-Fi router if it should cover area of radius N meters? Supposing area is without any barriers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. If you have the power of the transmitter, and its antenna gain, and the receiver's antenna gain, and its sensibility, then there is a relatively simple formula.

Now, the real question is if this will reflect the reality. Consumer product specifications are frequently over-rated and do not take into account negative effects of walls, reflections, interference, cable loss and many other factors. So the results have to be take with a fair bit of tolerance...

The formula is [here at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss). Look for FSPL(db).

Then you calculate Transmitter power + transmitter antenna gain + receiver antenna gain - PFPL(dB).

Receiver sensitivity should be better than that number (i.e. more negative).

Say:

```
Tx power     20dBm   (typical Wifi transmitter)
Tx ant gain   6dB    (two-dipole antenna)
Rx ant gain   0dB    (single dipole)
Path loss  - 80dB    (100m distance at 2.4GHz)
            -----
            -54dBm
```

Receiver sensitivity is normally around -60 - -90dBm, so you're good. As I said before - the reality is that such a setup will probably be marginal or fail.

EDIT: Found a simple spreadsheet I made a couple of years ago. It's interesting because the inverse formula is here too (loss -> distance). The green fields are for user input. I don't think I can make binary attachments here, but I've listed the formulas:

[image: Screenshot of path_loss spreadsheet]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case I have a large field without any large buildings, high hills and almost without trees. So I think calculations should be near the real values.

Comment: Well, at least require an extra margin of at least 6 - 10 dB. More if you're using the internal antenna of a phone, tablet or laptop. Remember you are not alone in the world. Others are competing for the same channels. And then there is always noise from other sources.

Comment: Basically, The antennas have to actually *see* each other. Some trees may be ok when it's not raining, but once wet, they represent a good shield (I had that experience myself!)

Comment: Yes, I understand this. On Zyxel site I found an article, that describes these losses: zyxel.ru/kb/2082 Unfortunately, I can find only russian version. [Here is translated table](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32463021/obstacles.JPG)

Comment: That's an interesting table, thanks. I wonder if this is for the frequency of WiFi signals? The numbers seem about what I read elsewhere, though they vary wildly from article to article. If you can't get there, try lifting or lowering the antennas!